# How to install python on a docker container

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, redis-sentinel

I have created a docker-compose yml file to run a cron-job in a docker container.

The cron-job which will run inside the docker container has to run a **python** script and connect to **mysql** an **redis** through redis-sentinel.

**Cron-job need python and required python-dependencies(mysql and redis sentinel)** to be installed in the docker container to run the python script successfully.

here is my docker-compose yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  cron-job:
    image: alpine:3.10
    command: crond -f -d 8
    volumes:
      - /Users/anshul/cron:/etc/crontabs/root:z
    restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: cnet
```

What changes I need to do here to have python and required dependencies installed on the docker container, which will come up after running this compose file.

Comment: You probably would be better off directly using a python image instead of alpine. Is alpine a requirement to you?

Comment: No, I do not need alpine, but what about the mysql and redis dependencies if i use python image.

Comment: if you also want to run them in docker, mysql and redis will have to be separate services

Comment: Yes, I have those running in my different docker containers, I just need to install mysql.connector and redis.sentinel dependencies in this container, so that cron can run python script.

Comment: They all should be in the same docker-compose file to share the same network. Then you probably have all the dependancies needed in your requirements.txt (as stated in the answer from @mikhail-pashkov)

Comment: The network part also I have taken care, all the docker-compose yml file(mysql and redis) has the same network as mentioned above cnet.

Comment: Ok, then just install your requirements as stated in the aswer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python image directly (if alpine is required, there is versions based on it) https://hub.docker.com/_/python
I think that best way to solve your request is build your own docker image:

#### create docker file

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

In this example you store your requirements in `requirements.txt` file.

Requirements file your can build with `pip freeze > requirements.txt` command (useful if you use virtual env's)

**or**

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir {mysql package name} {redis package name}
```

then you can push it in your docker hub registry, or build and use it directly from your docker-compose

#### Build your image and use with docker compose

1st way

You can build and push it to docker hub (here you can find more info: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/)

Then your docker compose will be like:

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  cron-job:
    image: dockerhub-login/your-image-name:tag
    ...
```

2nd way

You can use Dockerfile in docker-compose:

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  cron-job:
    build: path/to/Dockerfile
    ...
```

if `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yaml` in the same directory, then you can use `build: .`

Comment: but here you still need to run mysql and redis in separate services, like @fpietka mentioned above

Comment: The dependencies I need to install should be in separate lines right, in requirement.txt file.

Comment: for now i have done it through RUN pip install --no-cache-dir {mysql package name} {redis package name}